# How to use Conversational Retrieval Agent to get a final answer with reference sources

Tags: python, agent, langchain

Langchain has published a new Agent called Conversational Retrieval Agent. My ploblem is How to use Conversational Retrieval Agent to get a final answer with reference sources like by using create_qa_with_sources_chain function to created?

I have tried to make a SuffDocumentChain as a tool, however the final answer does not get the reference sources that are used to answer. If I just use the retriever as a tool, which will return the relevent docs from vector db, I can not find there is some place that I can tell the agent to use AnswerWithSources class to be the final output format.

Comment: there's no direct "create_qa_with_sources_chain" function or "AnswerWithSources" class in popular NLP libraries like Hugging Face's Transformers or Langchain's Conversational Retrieval Agent. However, if you're looking to achieve a similar functionality where you want to retrieve answers along with their reference sources, you might need to implement a custom solution or use existing components in a specific way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the following agent executor

```
agent_executor = create_conversational_retrieval_agent(llm=llm, tools=tools, verbose=True)
```

Then, the following should work

```
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever() # or whatever retriever you are using

tool = create_retriever_tool(
    retriever, 
    "search_docs",
    "Searches and returns documents."
)
tools = [tool]

query = "what is the definition of attention?"
result = agent_executor({"input": query})
# Get the answer to the query
print(result["output"])
# Get the sources
print(retriever.get_relevant_documents(query))
```

Comment: But then you are making duplicated calls to the database

Comment: @LucianoViola where is the second call to the database? Is it the `get_relevant_documents` call?